# check if it's File

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I have written very small code to check if it's file. I was expecting I should get "yes" print but I did not get. Am I doing any silly mistake.

```
os.listdir(os.getcwd()+"/../py")
a = ['a.py', 'a.pyc']
>>> for _a in a:
...  if os.path.isfile(_a):
...     print "yes"
```

Comment: Supply the _path_ to the file as an input (your files don't seem to be in the current working directory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a *full path*; you are only providing a relative path, so Python looks in the current working directory for these and there is no file named `a.py` in `os.getcwd()`.

Start by storing the path to the other directory in a variable:

```
path = os.path.abspath('../py')
for name in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name):
        print "yes", name, "is a file!"
```

I used `os.path.abspath()` instead of `os.getcwd()` to turn your relative path into a normalized absolute path, and used `os.path.join()` to then use that path to construct absolute paths for the list of names that `os.listdir()` returned.

Answer (score 1):

`a.py` looks for the file named `a.py` *in the current directory*. Your code seems to imply that you should be supplying a path (`../py`?)

For example:

```
>>> for _a in a:
...  if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('../py', _a)):
...     print "yes"
```